# How to assign contiguous numbers to groups of rows to create unique keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this kind of DataFrame in Spark

```
+---+--------+-----+
|  A|    date|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  3|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  3|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  4|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  4|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  3|12/06/15| 65,4|
|  3|17/06/15| 40,7|
|  4|12/06/15| 73,1|
|  4|17/06/15| 33,3|
....
+---+--------+-----+
```

where the `A` values are periodic: `1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> ...`

What I need to do is to add another column `T` to create a unique key `{T, A, date}` for my records:

```
+---+---+--------+-----+
|  T|  A|    date|value|
+---+---+--------+-----+
|  1|  1|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|  1|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|  3|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|  3|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|  4|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  1|  4|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  2|  1|12/06/15|  0,0|
|  2|  1|17/06/15|  0,0|
|  2|  3|12/06/15| 65,4|
|  2|  3|17/06/15| 40,7|
|  2|  4|12/06/15| 73,1|
|  2|  4|17/06/15| 33,3|
........
+---+---+--------+-----+
```

I saw that the `withColumn` DataFrame method allows adding additional columns to DF and that it is possible to compute `T` values out of other elements of the current row. The problem I'm facing here is that I would like to increment the value of the new `T` column if and only if there is already an element  with the same `{A, date}` value in the original DF.

What is the best way to do this in Spark?

Comment: @zero323 It is contiguous data: the point is the original dataset is missing the additional Id I'm trying to rebuild

Comment: If that's the case there is no generic and _efficient_ solution with Spark SQL alone. And if you drop SQL then it is just a variant of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35154267/1560062, don't you think?