# PySpark Data Frame - give an ID to sequence of same values

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset in a pyspark job that looks a bit like this:

```
frame_id    direction_change  
1           False  
2           False  
3           False  
4           True  
5           False
```

I want to add a "track" counter to each row so that all the frames between direction changes have the same value. For example, the output I want looks like this:

```
frame_id    direction_change    track
1           False               1
2           False               1
3           False               1
4           True                2
5           False               2
```

I have been able to do this with Pandas with the following action:

```
frames['track'] = frames['direction_change'].cumsum()
```

But can't find an equivalent way to do it in Spark data frames.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short there is no efficient way to do in PySpark with `DataFrames` alone. One could be tempted to use window functions like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum as sum_
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().orderBy("frame_id")

df.withColumn("change", 1 + sum_(col("direction_change").cast("long")).over(w))
```

but this inefficient and won't scale. It is possible to use lower level APIs as show in [How to compute cumulative sum using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35154267/1560062) but in Python it requires moving out of `Dataset` / `Dataframe` API and using plain RDDs.