# Multiline Spark sliding window

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Apache Spark with Scala and would like to use it to process a DNA data set that spans multiple lines like this:

```
ATGTAT
ACATAT
ATATAT
```

I want to map this into groups of a fixed size *k* and count the groups.  So for k=3, we would get groups of each character with the next two characters:

```
ATG TGT GTA TAT ATA TAC 
ACA CAT ATA TAT ATA TAT 
ATA TAT ATA TAT
```

...then count the groups (like word count):

```
(ATA,5), (TAT,5), (TAC,1), (ACA,1), (CAT,1), (ATG,1), (TGT,1), (GTA,1)
```

The problem is that the "words" span multiple lines, as does `TAC` in the example above.  It spans the line wrap.  I don't want to just count the groups in each line, but in the whole file, ignoring line endings.

In other words, I want to process the entire sequence as a sliding window of width *k* over the entire file as though there were no line breaks.  The problem is looking ahead (or back) to the next RDD row to complete a window when I get to the end of a line.

Two ideas I had were:

1. Append k-1 characters from the next line:

> ```
> ATATATAC
> ACATATAT
> ATATAT
> ```

I tried this with the Spark SQL lead() function, but when I tried executing a flatMap, I got a NotSerializableException for WindowSpec.  Is there any other way to reference the next line?  Would I need to write a custom input format?

2. Read the entire sequence in as a single line (or join lines after reading):

> ```
> ATATATACATATATATAT
> ```

Is there a way to read multiple lines so they can be processed as one?  If so, would it all need to fit into the memory of a single machine?

I realize either of these could be done as a pre-processing step.  I was wondering the best way is to do it within Spark.  Once I have it in either of these formats, I know how to do the rest, but I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a rdd of single character string instead of join them as one line, since that will make the result a string which can not be distributed:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("gene.txt")
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = gene.txt MapPartitionsRDD[4] at textFile at <console>:24
```

So simply use `flatMap` to split the lines into List of characters:

```
rdd.flatMap(_.split("")).collect
// res4: Array[String] = Array(A, T, G, T, A, T, A, C, A, T, A, T, A, T, A, T, A, T)
```

---

A more complete solution borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154267/how-to-compute-cumulative-sum-using-spark):

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("gene.txt")

// create the sliding 3 grams for each partition and record the edges
val rdd1 = rdd.flatMap(_.split("")).mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => {
  val slideList = iter.toList.sliding(3).toList
  Iterator((slideList, (slideList.head, slideList.last)))
})

// collect the edge values, concatenate edges from adjacent partitions and broadcast it
val edgeValues = rdd1.values.collect

val sewedEdges = edgeValues zip edgeValues.tail map { case (x, y) => {
  (x._2 ++ y._1).drop(1).dropRight(1).sliding(3).toList
}}

val sewedEdgesMap = sc.broadcast(
  (0 until rdd1.partitions.size) zip sewedEdges toMap
)

// sew the edge values back to the result
rdd1.keys.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => iter ++ List(sewedEdgesMap.value.getOrElse(i, Nil))).
  flatMap(_.map(_ mkString "")).collect

// res54: Array[String] = Array(ATG, TGT, GTA, TAT, ATA, TAC, ACA, CAT, ATA, TAT, ATA, TAT, ATA, TAT, ATA, TAT)
```

Comment: I think the question remains: how can I access elements two positions ahead of the current element.  So if I'm on the first element 'A', how can I look ahead a make a group of the next two: 'ATG'?  I know when it is in a String or array I can look ahead and concatenate based on the index, but what about RDD rows?

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154267/how-to-compute-cumulative-sum-using-spark)

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I'll have to go over it to understand what's going on.