# Unable to Convert to DataFrame from RDD after applying partitioning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Spark 2.1.0

When i am trying to use Window function on a Dataframe

```
val winspec = Window.partitionBy("partition_column")
DF.withColumn("column", avg(DF("col_name")).over(winspec))
```

My Plan changes and add the below lines to the Physical Plan and due to this An Extra Stage , EXtra Shuffling is happening and the Data is Huge which Slows down my Query like anything & runs for Hours.

```
+- Window [avg(cast(someColumn#262 as double)) windowspecdefinition(partition_column#460, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS someColumn#263], [partition_column#460]
   +- *Sort [partition_column#460 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(partition_column#460, 200)
```

Also i see the Stage as MapInternalPartition which i think is partitioned internally Now i don't know what is this. But because i think because of this even my 100 tasks took 30+ mins and in that 99 was completed within 1-2 mins and the last 1 task took remaining 30 mins leaving my cluster IDLE with no parallel processing which makes me think that is the data partitioned properly when Window function is used ???

I Tried to apply **HashPartitioning by converting it to RDD**...  BECAUSE we **cannot apply Custom / HashPartitioner on a Dataframe**

So if i do this :

```
val myVal = DF.rdd.partitioner(new HashPartitioner(10000))
```

I am getting a return type of **ANY** with which i am not getting any Action list to perform.

I checked and saw that the column with which the Partitioning is happening in Window functions contains all NULL values

Comment: it seems your data is heavily skewed

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**:

1. A shuffle when using window functions is not **extra**. It is required for correctness and cannot be removed.
2. Applying partitioner shuffles.
3. Datasets cannot reuse RDD partitioning. Partitioning with `Dataset` should be done with `repartition` method:

   ```
   df.repartition($"col_name")
   ```
4. But it won't help you because of 2)
5. And this:

   ```
   val myVal = DF.rdd.partitioner(new HashPartitioner(10000))
   ```

   wouldn't return `Any`. It wouldn't compile, as there is no `partitioner` method for `RDD`, which takes arguments.

   Correct method is `partitionBy` but it is not applicable to `RDD[Row]` and it wouldn't help you because of 3).

If there is enough memory you can try

```
df.join(
  broadcast(df.groupBy("partition_column").agg(avg(DF("col_name"))),
  Seq("partition_column")
)
```

**Edit**:

If you're trying to compute running average (`avg` with `Window.partitionBy("partition_column")` computes global average by group, not running average), then you're out of luck.

If partitioning column has only `NULLS`, then task is not distributed and fully sequential.

To compute global running average you can try to apply logic similar to this [How to compute cumulative sum using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35154267/8371915).

Comment: What is Sequential Dependency can u please explain a little and what is the impact u see over here ..?