# How to create a cumulative summation column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Finding cumulative summations or, means are very very common operations in data analysis and yet in pyspark all the solutions that I see online tend to bring all the data in one partition which would not work for really large datasets.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum

# Step 1: Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Step 2: Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "Alice", 100),
    (2, "Bob", 200),
    (3, "Charlie", 150),
    (4, "David", 300),
    (5, "Eve", 250)
], ["ID", "Name", "Value"])

# Step 3: Sort the DataFrame and compute cumulative sum
window_spec = Window.orderBy("ID").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
df = df.withColumn("CumulativeSum", sum(col("Value")).over(window_spec))

# Step 4: Show the DataFrame with cumulative sum
df.show()
```

How are cumulative aggregations handled in pyspark?

Comment: What do you mean by _tend to bring all the data in one partition_? Spark is a distributed query engine and I am pretty certain that the windowed `sum` would also be calculated in a distributed fashion

Comment: If you try running the code that I have posted above you will see the warnings that I am referring to. If you can find a way to add cumulations in a distributed fashion please post it as an answer. That would be of great help

Comment: Need to do your own via rdds

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154267/how-to-compute-cumulative-sum-using-spark Try this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute cumulative sum using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154267/how-to-compute-cumulative-sum-using-spark)